# Bootstrap 4.0 hiding elements not working inside ng-template

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am working with Angular 6 + Angular Material and have Bootstrap 4.0.0 included.

In below code:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="stepOne">
    <ng-template class="d-none d-sm-block" matStepLabel>Customer Information</ng-template>
      <...>
  </mat-step>
```

I want to make "Customer Information" text hidden on xs-devices, but "d-none d-sm-block" class is not working. Creating and assigning the class to "div" tag doesn't work as well.

What am I doing wrong, and how this can be solved? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to nest a element into the template? `<ng-template matStepLabel><span class="d-none d-sm-block">Customer Information</span></ng-template>`

Comment: Worked perfectly! I should have figured it by myself... Thank you very much ;)